# conda error : install package

Tags: linux, python, anaconda

i try to install conda-forge spacy and use this command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge spacy
```

and get this error:

> Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
>   Solving environment: failed
>   Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
>   Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

- anaconda==2019.03=py37_0 -> anaconda-client==1.7.2=py37_0 -> nbformat -> jsonschema[version='>=2.4,!=2.5.0']
- anaconda==2019.03=py37_0 -> importlib_metadata==0.8=py37_0
- anaconda==2019.03=py37_0 -> pango==1.42.4=h049681c_0
- jsonschema
- pkgs/main/linux-64::_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf==0.1.0=py37_0 -> ipywidgets -> nbformat[version='>=4.2.0'] -> jsonschema[version='>=2.4,!=2.5.0']
- pkgs/main/linux-64::anaconda-client==1.7.2=py37_0 -> nbformat -> jsonschema[version='>=2.4,!=2.5.0']
- pkgs/main/linux-64::anaconda-navigator==1.9.7=py37_0 -> anaconda-client[version='>=1.6.14'] -> nbformat[version='>=4.4.0'] -> jsonschema[version='>=2.4,!=2.5.0']
- pkgs/main/linux-64::importlib_metadata==0.8=py37_0
- pkgs/main/linux-64::ipywidgets==7.4.2=py37_0 -> nbformat[version='>=4.2.0'] -> jsonschema[version='>=2.4,!=2.5.0']
- pkgs/main/linux-64::jupyter==1.0.0=py37_7 -> ipywidgets -> nbformat[version='>=4.2.0'] -> jsonschema[version='>=2.4,!=2.5.0']
- pkgs/main/linux-64::jupyterlab==0.35.4=py37hf63ae98_0 -> jupyterlab_server[version='>=0.2.0,<0.3.0'] -> notebook -> nbconvert -> nbformat[version='>=4.4'] -> jsonschema[version='>=2.4,!=2.5.0']
- pkgs/main/linux-64::jupyterlab_server==0.2.0=py37_0 -> notebook -> nbconvert -> nbformat[version='>=4.4'] -> jsonschema[version='>=2.4,!=2.5.0']
- pkgs/main/linux-64::nbconvert==5.4.1=py37_3 -> nbformat[version='>=4.4'] -> jsonschema[version='>=2.4,!=2.5.0']
- pkgs/main/linux-64::nbformat==4.4.0=py37_0 -> jsonschema[version='>=2.4,!=2.5.0']
- pkgs/main/linux-64::notebook==5.7.8=py37_0 -> nbconvert -> nbformat[version='>=4.4'] -> jsonschema[version='>=2.4,!=2.5.0']
- pkgs/main/linux-64::pango==1.42.4=h049681c_0
- pkgs/main/linux-64::path.py==11.5.0=py37_0 -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.5']
- pkgs/main/linux-64::spyder==3.3.3=py37_0 -> nbconvert -> nbformat[version='>=4.4'] -> jsonschema[version='>=2.4,!=2.5.0']
- pkgs/main/linux-64::widgetsnbextension==3.4.2=py37_0 -> notebook[version='>=4.4.1'] -> nbconvert -> nbformat[version='>=4.4'] -> jsonschema[version='>=2.4,!=2.5.0']

Comment: I find another way to install spacy. and i use pip:
pip install spacy